# How many players using Game Center or waiting for a game

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Is there a way to learn how many players using Game Center or waiting for a game to play ? In my application there is a scene where you select the type of game you are going to play. There are three types "Single Player" "Multiplayer" and "Multiplayer via Game Center". I want to show how many players playing using game center to the user and how many players are trying to find a match. 
I want to know if there is a way to know it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to show how many users are currently using my app and logged in with game center.
First make a leaderboard, call it something like "Online Players". Make it's Score Submission Type "the most recent score" and sort order "high to low". When users authenticates with game center send 1 to your leaderboard and when application goes background send 1 to your leaderboard. Ask for the leaderboard scores where you want to show the online players and get highest 100 values. Set timeScope GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday and range 100 (MAX). Only bad part is that max value, you can show only 100 players online and if you get more online players, you can't show them.